# Pressure cooker

Tags: pressure

When a pressure cooker reaches it's operating temperature and pressure, is the water in the pressure cooker boiling?  Or does the elevated pressure that is responsible for raising the boiling point of the water, keep the water just from boiling?

Comment: The water is boiling.

Comment: I think that under normal operation that the cooking temperature of a pressure cooker is at or very near the pressure-elevated boiling temperature of water.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/776035/226902