# Why doesn't a pressure cooker reach equilibrium?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Why doesn't a pressure cooker reach a state of equilibrium where the steam passed is constant (assuming the contents of the cooker are maintained throughout the cooking process), but rather, it accumulates pressure until it releases it in the form of a whistle every so often? I don't understand why the pressure "overshoots" and releases more than what would keep the weight open, and then releases more than is needed for the weight to lower. I suspect this has to do with the static friction which needs to be overcome for the whistle to rise being greater than the dynamic friction, or something along those lines.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/345086/226902

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, pressure inside is equal to atmospheric pressure. Pressure applied on the valve is greater downwards, due to the weight of the valve plus the atmospheric pressure. This is equalized by the normal force from the pressure cooker.

p(Atm) + mg/a = p(Atm) + N(initial)

As the pressure builds up in the cooker, the system stays in equilibrium by subsequently reducing the normal force. You can think of this as a rope tugging on a person standing on a scale. The person might not be lifted up, but their weight on the scale will reduce.

p(Atm) + mg/a = p(Cooker) + N(control)

After a certain point, the normal force becomes 0 and the pressure built has to be released. In theory, the gas released should be miniscule, and it would immediately return to near 0 normal force (oscillating process). But something similar to the siphon effect keeps it open for a while longer, and the process repeats until you run out of gas.

I don’t have many sources for the siphon effect part of my answer, but the rest seems mathematically sound.

Comment: I imagine the valve would become wet, and surface tension would hold it closed until the pressure inside exceeds atmospheric pressure *plus* enough to break the surface tension. Then the inside pressure would need some time to drop back to atmospheric pressure + mg/a.

Comment: I suppose there could be many such factors contributing to the answer. But if it worked purely on surface tension, the valve wouldn't have to be weighted. A simple wooden or plastic valve would work just as well. 

The weight of the valve probably provides most of the downward force, while the surface tension and friction are secondary forces.