# Pressure Cooker Energy Usage Optimization

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

I have a pressure cooker with a 15 PSI regulator weight which should regulate the temperature inside the pressure cooker to about 250 degrees F.

What I have noticed is that, if I add more weights (coins, whatnot) on top of the regulator to increase its weight, I can reduce the amount of heat I apply to the pressure cooker and still maintain 15 PSI.

As I continue to add coins to increase the weight of the regulator, I can continue to decrease the heat of the stove and still maintain 15 PSI in the cooker.

My questions are, is the temperature inside a pressure cooker at 15 PSI still about 250 degress F with the additional weights and less heat? Am I increasing the efficiency of the pressure cooker by adding weights to the regulator and reducing the heat?

I would like to point out that, throughout the entire experiment, the pressure guage never goes over 15 PSI, so there should be no risk of "explosion".

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610392/226902

Answer (score 2):

The weight on the pressure cooker is calibrated to ensure that venting of steam occurs at 15 psi.  Adding additional weight (e.g., coins) ensures that you run the pressure cooker at a pressure that is higher than 15 psi.  This is a potentially dangerous thing to do!  Not only does the original weight ensure 15 psi in the pressure cooker, it also acts as a pressure relief valve to ensure that you do not over-pressure the pressure cooker.  It is entirely conceivable that you will add enough weight to the original weight to exceed the design pressure of the pressure cooker ... and believe me, you DON'T WANT an exploding pressure cooker in your kitchen.  STOP doing your pressure cooker optimization experiments!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62128/discussion-on-answer-by-david-white-pressure-cooker-energy-usage-optimization).